# Почему RewriteRule не работает?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть строка `/game/rebus/1/`, может быть `/game/rebus?page=3&perpage=10` с разными параметрами.
Правило редиректа:
`RewriteRule ^game/([\w]*)\/*([\w\d]*)\/*\?*([\w\d\&\=]*) game.php?type=$1&id=$2&$3 [NC,L]`
В первом случае все работает нормально, во втором подстрока `page=3&perpage=10` в запрос не попадает.
Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После многих проб мне удалось таки добиться того, что нужно. Так как часть после ? упорно игнорировалась в RewriteRule, попробовал вынести определение подстроки в RewriteCond и все заработало.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \??(.*)$
RewriteRule ^game/([\w]*)/*([\w\d]*)/* game.php?type=$1&id=$2&%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваше правило RewriteRule не учитывает тот факт, что параметры могут отсутствовать или быть пустыми. Поэтому вы можете использовать следующее правило:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([\w]*)/?([\w\d]*)/?(\?[\w\d\&\=]*)?$ game.php?type=$1&id=$2&$3 [NC,L]
```

В этом правиле я добавил знак вопроса (?) в конце каждой группы квантификатора, чтобы указать, что эти группы могут быть необязательными. Также я добавил опцию (?[\w\d&=]*)? для обработки параметров запроса, которые могут отсутствовать или быть пустыми.

Обратите внимание, что в этом правиле я использую квантификатор + вместо *, чтобы указать, что эти группы должны содержать хотя бы один символ. Это поможет избежать ситуаций, когда в запросе параметры отсутствуют, но в вашем правиле они учитываются.

Например, учитывая это правило, строка /game/rebus/1/ будет разобрана следующим образом:

```
type будет равно rebus
id будет равно 1
$3 будет пустым
```

А строка `/game/rebus?page=3&perpage=10` будет разобрана следующим образом:

```
type будет равно rebus
id будет пустым
$3 будет равно page=3&perpage=10
```

Comment: Увы, но это не срабатывает. Подстрока `page=3&perpage=10` все равно не попадает. Попробовал разобрать таким способом - `RewriteRule ^game/([^\?/]+)(.*) game.php?type=$1&text=$2 [NC,L]`, получается `type=rebus&text=/`, то есть, после ? обрезается. Думал, дело в повторении вопросительного знака, но если сделать `RewriteRule ^game/([^\?/]+)(.*) game.php$2&type=$1 [NC,L]`, получается `page=1&perpage=2`, а type обрезается.

Comment: Попробуйте это `RewriteRule ^game/([\w]*)/*([\w\d]*)/*\?*([\w\d\&\=]*) game.php?type=$1&id=$2&$3 [NC,L]`

Comment: Не получается все равно, page и perpage в GET не попадают.